# Angular HTTPClient altered specify string in response data

Tags: angular, httpclient

I'm using angular9.
The httpclient altered the specified string in response data from API.

This is header:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({});
const httpOptions = {
            headers,
            withCredentials: true,
            responseType: 'text',
            params
        };
```

Handle response data:

```
request.subscribe((response) => {
            let data;
            try {
                data = JSON.parse(response);
            } catch(err) {
                data = response;
            }
        }
```

The real data is `"country":"Åland Islands"`
But the response altered to `"country":"Ã[]land Islands"`

[image]

**Update question**:
The error occurs when I submit data, value in DB is altered:

```
Request Payload:
{country: "Åland Islands"}
 
And Response:
{country: "Ãland Islands"}
```

Comment: Can you try setting `data = response` without the `JSON.parse` or try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))`?

Comment: @CodeWarrior, it's not working. I used response type is text. And the response data was altered before I parse JSON.

Comment: You need to check it in the backend code in that case.

Comment: @ThuyNguyen that is something on the backend side. By the way, did you try to use responseType: 'json' ? I'm not familiar with your backend but it probably means something

Comment: Oh my gosh, I already re-check, and see the error occurs while I post the data, I updated my question